# Find all lines beginning with a digit

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the regex to extract all lines beginning with a digit?

I know the `^` character is used to match anything at the beginning of the line but I am not constructing it correct.

Here is what I have tried :

```
re.findall('^[0-9]+',mystring).
```

Comment: so what is happening? what is your input, what is your output, what have you tried doing to fix the problem, ...

Comment: You forget the `MULTILINE` modifier and `.*` to match the rest of the line. However, it is not the best way. Split with `\n` and iterate through the lines checking if the first char is a digit. See http://ideone.com/dO4AYB

Comment: ^^Yup. That's exactly what I would do too.

Comment: Seconded^. Seems like an approach better suited to solving this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to match the entire the line but it is only matching the starting number. You need to include the greedy wildcard as well as the multiline argument to tell it you want to search many lines. Try:

```
re.findall('^[0-9].*', mystring, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: There is no point in using `+` after `[0-9]`. It will work even without it.

Comment: You are correct.  I just copied the question's code and put the fix in without looking too thoroughly at it.

Answer (score 4):

You forget the `re.MULTILINE` modifier and `.*` after `[0-9]` to match the rest of the line. If you *were* to use a regex, you would use `r"(?m)^[0-9].*"`:

```
re.findall(r"(?m)^[0-9].*", mystring)
```

The `(?m)` multiline inline modifier, equal to `re.MULTILINE` or `re.M` options, makes `^` match start of *lines* and `$` match end of *lines*, not just start/end of the *whole string*.

However, it is not the best way. Split with \n and iterate through the lines checking if the first char is a digit.

Here is what I suggest:

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line and line[0].isdigit():
            print(line)
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/1cZLnP)

Comment: you mean if len(line) > 0 and line[0].isdigit() right? your solution is causing index out of range

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar Yes, it should be `len(line) > 0`, not `line[0]`.

Comment: You don't even need to check the length of the line, 'if line' will do the job.

Comment: @MarkLawrence I knew Python much less 4 years ago.